# "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured" with django 1.6

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am developing on win7 with pycharm 3 with python/django on a portable environment. I've decided to try to add postgresql to my project ("rob1") which is inside my virtualenv "R1" and I have using http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgsqlportable/

I changed my settings.py to include:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '123',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
}
```

after creating a model from the polls tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) as a test, I ran syncdb and got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PyCharm 3.0.1\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "f:\ppython275\App\Lib\runpy.py", line 176, in run_module
    fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "f:\ppython275\App\Lib\runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "f:\ppython275\App\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "F:\envs\r1\rob1\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 157, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Running manage.py diffsettings I get

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
BASE_DIR = 'F:\\envs\\r1\\rob1\\rob1'  ###
DATABASES = {'default': {'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'NAME': '', 'TEST_MIRROR': None, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TEST_NAME': None, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_COLLATION': None, 'PORT': '', 'HOST': '', 'USER': '', 'TEST_CHARSET': None, 'PASSWORD': '', 'OPTIONS': {}}}
DEBUG = True
INSTALLED_APPS = ('django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'getPost', 'gunicorn')
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
ROOT_URLCONF = 'rob1.urls'  ###
SECRET_KEY = '****'
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SETTINGS_MODULE = 'rob1.settings'  ###
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('F:\\envs\\r1\\rob1\\rob1\\static',)
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'rob1.wsgi.application'    

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Edit: more error info above, There is only one settings.py file  (in rob1)

Now that you started me looking There is an additional area in settings .py:

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

Can anyone advise me how to fix this?

Comment: Do you only have one settings file, `rob1/settings.py`, or are you importing other files? Does your settings file only contain one `DATABASES` assignment? Also, what other errors do you get?

Comment: Please see edit ( and thanks for looking at it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `dj_database_url.config()`, you also need to set `DATABASE_URL`:

```
DATABASE_URL = "postgres://postgres:123@localhost:5432/test"
#                          ^user    ^pw ^host     ^port ^dbname
```

Comment: where do you put DATABASE_URL = "postgres://postgres:123@localhost:5432/test" to set it?

Comment: You can either put it into an environment variable, or put it into your settings like this `DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default="postgres://postgres:123@localhost:5432/test")`